# Unable to change Ribbon Color

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

In my SharePoint 2010 Site the ribbon color is set to green ,But my client wishes to have Gray .So I tried with below 3 css code styles and integrated to file to master page.

But I don't see any result,Can any one help me how can I overcome from the issue as I have below pasted the designer code

```
body #PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation{
    background-color: gray;
}

body #s4-ribbonrow {
    background-color: gray;
}


.ribbioncolor{
    background-color: gray;

}


Designer Code
------------
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" runat="server">

        <table CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0 WIDTH="100%">
        <tr>
         <td colspan=4 class="ms-globalbreadcrumb">

            <span id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display:none">

               <a href="#" class="ms-skip" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();return false;">

            <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnonaccessibility%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>

            </span>

<A href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:this.href='#mainContent';" class="ms-skip" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,maincontent_accesskey%>" runat="server">

<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,mainContentLink%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></A>

<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=100% class="ms-globalleft">

<tr>

<td class="ms-globallinks" style="padding-top: 2px;" height=100% valign=middle>

<div>

<span id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display:none">

<a href="#" class="ms-acclink" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();return false;">


<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnoffaccessibility%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>

</span>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server">

<asp:SiteMapPath SiteMapProvider="SPSiteMapProvider" id="GlobalNavigationSiteMap" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" SkipLinkText="" NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-sitemapdirectional" runat="server"/>

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</div>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height=100% class="ms-globalright">

<tr>

<td valign="middle" class="ms-globallinks" style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:6px;">

<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="GlobalSiteLink0"/>

</td>

<td valign="middle" class="ms-globallinks">

<wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">

</wssuc:Welcome>

</td>

<td style="padding-left:1px;padding-right:3px;" class="ms-globallinks">|</td>

<td valign="middle" class="ms-globallinks">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>

<td class="ms-globallinks">

<SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink1" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/></td>

<td class="ms-globallinks">

<SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink2" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/></td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

<td valign="middle" class="ms-globallinks">&nbsp;

<a href="javascript:TopHelpButtonClick('NavBarHelpHome')" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_accesskey%>" id="TopHelpLink" title="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" runat="server"><img align='absmiddle' border=0 src="/_layouts/images/helpicon.gif" alt="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" runat="server"></a>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in the `head` tag of master page

```
#s4-ribbonrow
{
    background-color:gray !important;
}
```

**How to add it to master page**

1. Open SharePoint Designer
2. Connect to the site in question
3. Open the "Style Library" folder
4. Create a new CSS file and name it (e.g. "customstyles.css")
5. Add the above css in the file and save it
6. Open your master page file in SPD
7. In the  tag add a link to your custom CSS just above the content place holder named `PlaceHolderAdditonalPageHead` as follows:

   ```
   <link href="/Style%20Library/customstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   ```

Your custom master page is now using your new CSS file in addition to all of the CSS files SharePoint uses out-of-the-box.

[Source](http://fitandfinish.ironworks.com/2010/01/the-best-way-to-add-custom-css-to-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Added ,But don't find any result.Can you please let me should I directly add the given css style or do I need to add any tag and then place the style

Comment: @mdsiddiqali i have updated my answer

Comment: I don't find any result hashim